# Clarify tag [inline]

Tags: discussion, tags

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528527/inline-block-not-working-because-of-white-space-nowrap) and a overview of uses for [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline).

This is not what the tag is made for, it's mis-understood/-used in ~50% of the tagged questions.

Can we make it more visible for new users that this is mainly a tag for C/C++? Mentioning C/C++ nearer the start of the tag description should do this easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be confusion here between [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline):

> An inline function is a function upon which the compiler has been requested to perform inline expansion. In other words, the programmer has requested that the compiler insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined. (However, compilers are not obligated to respect this request.)

and [inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-block):

> inline-block is a CSS display option which causes an element to be positioned (mostly) like an inline element, but otherwise behave (mostly) like a block element

I don't think that this is a problem with the text *per se*; it is clear what each refers to. I think the problem is that **the people who are misusing the tags aren't reading the text**. This can't be fixed by changing the text!

However, there is already [inline-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-functions):

> By using keyword 'inline' in function definition, programmer can request that the (C/C++) compiler insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined.

and a [whole load of other `inline`-related tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline+or+inline-assembly+or+inline-block+or+inline-editing+or+inline-formset+or+inline-code+or+inline-styles+or+inline-functions+or+inlines+or+inline-images+or+inline-method+or+inline-view+or+inlineuicontainer+or+inlineeditbox+or+inline-if+or+inline-scripting+or+inline-html+or+inline-namespaces+or+inline-c+or+inline-xml).

**I therefore suggest that [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) is burninated** (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286349/3001761)), and replaced with the more appropriate tags.

Comment: There are still [74 questions tagged with `css` and `inline`](http://stackoverflow.com/?tags=css%20inline&mode=all) and it’s still being mistagged. If we could remove [tag:inline] out of those and burninate [tag:inline] we would be only left with [tag:inline-functions].