# Request that the compiler insert a useful tag in every place that [inline] is used

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

As pointed out in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286347/3001761), [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) is widely misused. Although the tag description is:

> An inline function is a function upon which the compiler has been requested to perform inline expansion. In other words, the programmer has requested that the compiler insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined. (However, compilers are not obligated to respect this request.)

it is also used to refer to e.g. [inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-block) (and [lots of other related tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline+or+inline-assembly+or+inline-block+or+inline-editing+or+inline-formset+or+inline-code+or+inline-styles+or+inline-functions+or+inlines+or+inline-images+or+inline-method+or+inline-view+or+inlineuicontainer+or+inlineeditbox+or+inline-if+or+inline-scripting+or+inline-html+or+inline-namespaces+or+inline-c+or+inline-xml)). Additionally, the existing [inline-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-functions) refers to the same topic and is much less ambiguous (I can see no particular reason that `inline` should be considered synonymous with `inline-functions` rather than any of the other related tags).

I therefore think that `inline` should be replaced with more meaningful tags and burninated.

Comment: what compiler are you referring to? As far as I'm aware, the tags are added to the system (past and present) by reputable users. Their association to questions is managed by users..

Comment: I understand you're attempting to be less ambigious, but `inline` is not an attribute, keyword, or accessor in css; It is quite clearly a keyword as accessor of a function. `inline void hello()`

Comment: @BrettCaswell the title was a joke, along the lines of *"Unmount the [HDD]"* [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286177/3001761). And not all tags have to be keywords, the goal is to be unambiguous about what tags should refer to **on SO**, not reflect the syntax of any languages.

Comment: These users are not looking for [tag:inline-block]. The `display` property in CSS has three values which are most commonly used: `inline`, `inline-block`, and `block`. I don't believe that property is complicated enough to warrant separate tags, though. I'd recommend retagging all the CSS questions to just [tag:css] (as well as merging [tag:inline-block]) and making the [tag:inline] tag more specific as to its purpose.

Comment: @animuson [tag:inline-block] was just an example ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28508645/3001761) was a particularly unambiguous example of misuse), there are various other tags that relate to *"inline"*. If this CSS-related use is also not appropriate then that should go too. Do you disagree that [tag:inline] should be deprecated in favour of [tag:inline-functions]?

Comment: I do agree with you, I was just pointing out that not all CSS questions tagged with [tag:inline] are going to be about [tag:inline-block], as they are different values. I've gone ahead and synonymized [tag:inline-block] into [tag:css] though, so any CSS questions can just have the tag removed.

Comment: @animuson synonymized what exactly? you correctly pointed out that both `inline` and `inline-block` are enumerable values to `display` in **css**.. so are people going to be looking up answers for their issues with **css** and `inline`? and get `display:inline-block` Q&As?

Comment: @BrettCaswell I snyonymized [tag:inline-block] into [tag:css]. I did nothing with [tag:inline].

Comment: Well, I cleaned up all the 96 questions having assembly+inline. Most gained much more than just inline-assembly. And some got completely new tags and other polish.

Comment: @Deduplicator excellent work!

Comment: I'm not familiar with any language where that tag description is actually accurate :(  The tag wiki for [tag:inlining] appears to be exactly the same, where at least it is more relevant, although the mention of inline keywords is still inaccurate.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the wiki doesn't make mention to inline keywords.. were you referring to my comment above? I suppose I should correct that as **inline specifier**, and it's a **reserved word**. .. or, yeah, **keyword** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: @Brett: I'm talking about "the programmer has requested that the compiler insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called".  That clearly means the C++ `inline` keyword, but it is wrong.  C++ `inline` specifier (and C too, since I think C99) prevents "symbol multiply defined" errors and has only a very distant connection to the inlining optimization.

Comment: So, in all seriousness, it's not only the [tag:inline] tag on StackOverflow, but the `inline` keyword itself, that is badly misunderstood and widely misused.

Comment: @BenVoigt then Wikipedia's wrong too; feel free to edit that and the tag wiki, but I don't think that changes anything as far as this cleanup is concerned.

Comment: No, it really doesn't change the tagging discussion, except that a lot of questions tagged [tag:inline] should have [tag:inlining] instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt perhaps [tag:inlining] should be a synonym of [tag:inline-functions] or vice versa, they have the same description. [tag:inline] is too generic, I think it should go entirely.

Comment: I went over a few dozens of questions in the `c` tag.  For most of them, re-tagging from `inline` to `inline-functions` seemed appropriate but there were others that I didn't know how to deal with.  Actually, most of the questions were asking the same thing anyway and could have been closed if we had a canonical `inline` answer.  Anyway, there remain *hundreds* of questions in the `c` and `c++` tag…

Comment: @Ben, Thomas Eding wrote "Only one thing is guaranteed by the compiler when using inline, and it is NOT "inlining" a function's body. The real (and guaranteed by the standard) purpose of the inline is to prevent multiple definitions." in this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class .. is this the understood purpose of `inline` as you understand it to be?

Comment: btw, `inline-namespace` in C++?

Comment: @BrettCaswell: That's pretty much the case, except that it doesn't prevent multiple definitions, it allows them to coexist without error.  And this is what [tag:inline-functions] should be used for.  [tag:inlining] is good for questions related to the actual optimization.  Good point on `inline-namespace` also.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Those two have the same description because the description of [tag:inline-functions] is wrong (at least for C and C++).  [tag:inlining] refers to the optimization, actually inserting the code.  [tag:inline-functions] does not.